# Reading .JPG Image and Saving it without file size change

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer

I have a question regarding the library: http://imageresizing.net. After the code reads in a JPG image and then saves it, the [compression ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression_ratio) changes from 21.4 to 13.9. The original image size was 147,936 kB (at an aspect ratio of 1920 x 550), and the saved image is now 227,116 kB.

Any ideas about how to keep the saved image the same size as the original?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the same jpeg in Photoshop, then save it at 90% quality, you will see the same effect.

Jpegs increase in size every time they are re-saved. If you increase the quality value, they size will drastically increase.

Tell ImageResizer to use a different quality setting for images that are already low quality, or don't use it unless you actually want to edit the image.